# ssh connection between 2 clients over server

Tags: ssh

Hi my problem is i want to set up a ssh connection to my computer at home, but i am **not** able to do a dyn-dns routing because of my isp. I also got a vServer running.

My question now is: Is it possible to connect to the **vServer** from both my **PC at home** and my **Laptop** and somehow redirect the ssh, so i can ssh from my Laptop to my PC at home?

It is important, that they both first connect to the vServer as Clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: use remote port forwarding.

From the home box, establish an SSH connection to server with something like:

```
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 user@server
```

This means: "have server listen on port 2222, and forward connections thereon to "localhost:22" as viewed by the home box.

From your laptop, ssh to port 2222 on the vServer:

```
ssh -p 2222 server
```

This will be forwarded to port 22 on your home box.

This assumes that you can connect to 2222 from your laptop (and/or can't connect to anything other than 22 from home). There are ways around those assumptions.